# Comparison inside if statement?

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me is it possible to have an if statement similar to this? 
I want to check is the first list item with class FIRST really first li tag.
My firebug console throws me no errors but this code is not working...
Thank you!!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    if($('ul li.first')==$('ul li:first')){
        $('ul').css({'display':'none'});
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li class="first">One</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note, for future readers: If you want ti compare whether two jQuery elements point to the same element, use: `$("ul li.first")[0] == $("ul li:first")[0]` (notice `[0]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) traversal method:

```
if($('ul li.first').is(":first")){
    $('ul').css({'display':'none'}); // you can use `.hide()` here instead
}
```

you can also test the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
if($('ul li.first').index() === 0){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('ul li.first').is(':first')){
    $('ul').hide();
}
```